# Curving the cylinder in a periodic fashion

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3d

I have to implement an array made up of cylindrical like elements. However, below code can only provide a straight cylinder (code credit goes to [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/469721/120078)), instead I need to bend it like in the figure shown, may not be at that angle but vertical. But I couldn't seem to succeed. I couldn't even seem to increase the number of cylinder from one to more.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{8,108,131}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{cylinder end fill/.style={path picture={
            \pgftransformshift{\centerpoint}%
            \pgftransformrotate{\rotate}%  
            \pgfpathmoveto{\beforetop}%
            \pgfpatharc{90}{-270}{\xradius and \yradius}%
            \pgfpathclose
            \pgfsetfillcolor{#1}%
            \pgfusepath{fill}}
}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \path let \p1=(0.2,8.4),
    \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)},\n2={veclen(\y1,\x1)} in
    node[cylinder, rotate=270,
    minimum height=0.85*\n2,minimum width=1cm,aspect=1.0,
    cylinder end fill=red,
    left color=red!30,right color=black,middle color=red!80, opacity=0.7,
    draw] at (0.8,4.7) {1};
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure if Ti*k*Z is the best tool to do this if you want all the lighting as in the screen shot. With `asymptote` you can draw nice pipes, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/404274.

Comment: If you do not want the lighting (nor the perspective view) it is trivial to draw this.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I actually need perspective. But I couldn't get the lightning part? You mean the grayish coloring?

Comment: Yes. The fact that the color is not uniform. It is nontrivial to get this with Ti*k*Z, in particular if it is supposed to look semi-realistic.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Aah I see, I don't need such a shade. It is not really important for me, only perspective, I would say.

Comment: I love the design... is it a bus from an electrical circuit? :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano It is an optical waveguide in a silica medium.

Comment: @Shamina It is very nice your drawing instead of Schrödinger's cat :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an answer which produces something long these lines. The key ingredient is the `perspective` library. It utilizes a [nice trick by Symbol 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365418/194703) (and, as usual, the really cool things do not have much votes... ;-) which allows us to avoid to write `tpp cs:x=...,y=...,z=...`, we can just coordinates and the switch `switch on perspective`. Since decorations cause `dimension too large` errors, the color gradient and change of line width is achieved through loops, which is why this takes some time to compile (12s on a 5 year old MacBook Pro). A faster, decoration-based answer that works for not too curvy paths can be found below.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,perspective,3d}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{switch on perspective/.code={\def\tikz@parse@splitxyz##1##2##3,##4,{%
    \def\pgfutil@next{\tikz@scan@one@point##1(tpp cs:x={##2},y={##3},z={##4})}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365418/194703
}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={-70}{15}]
 \begin{scope}[perspective={p = {(20,0,0)}, q = {(0,20,0)}},switch on perspective]
  \path let \p1=($(0,2,0)-(0,0,0)$),\p2=($(20,2,0)-(20,0,0)$),
     \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)/2+atan2(\y2,\x2)/2} in
   [left color=black,right color=gray!80!black,shading angle=\n1]
    (0,-3,0) -- (0,3,0) -- (20,3,0) -- (20,-3,0) -- cycle;
  \begin{scope}
   \clip (1,-3,0) -- (1,3,0) -- (20,3,0) -- (20,-3,0) -- cycle;
   \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,1.2,-1.2,-2}
   {\foreach \Z [evaluate=\Z as \CF using {int(90-\Z/3)}] in {1,...,95}
   {\draw let 
    \p1=($(0.8+\Z/5,\X+0.5,0)-(0.8+\Z/5,\X-0.5,0)$),
    \n1={sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)} in [line width=0.1*\n1,gray!\CF!black]
    plot[variable=\t,domain=0.8+\Z/5:0.8+\Z/5+0.4,samples=5,smooth] 
    (\t,{\X+0.2*pow(-1,\Y+1)*isodd(int(\t/2.05))},0) ;}}
  \path foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,1.2,-1.2,-2}
   {(1,{\X+pow(-1,\Y+1)*0.2*isodd(int(1/2.05))},0) coordinate (aux\Y) };        
  \end{scope}   
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \fill[rotate=-15] foreach \X in {1,...,4} {(aux\X) circle[x radius=5pt,y radius=1pt]};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For straight cylinders there is no problem, the decoration is well-behaved.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations,perspective,3d}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{switch on perspective/.code={\def\tikz@parse@splitxyz##1##2##3,##4,{%
    \def\pgfutil@next{\tikz@scan@one@point##1(tpp cs:x={##2},y={##3},z={##4})}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365418/194703
}}}
\makeatother
% the following decoration is based on
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14295/128068 and
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/471222
\pgfkeys{/pgf/decoration/.cd,
         start color/.store in=\startcolor,
         start color=black,
         end color/.store in=\endcolor,
         end color=black,
         varying line width steps/.initial=100
}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{width and color change}{initial}{
 \state{initial}[width=0pt, next state=line, persistent precomputation={%
   \pgfmathparse{\pgfdecoratedpathlength/\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/varying line width steps}}%
   \let\increment=\pgfmathresult%
   \def\x{0}%
 }]{}
 \state{line}[width=\increment pt,   persistent postcomputation={%
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\x+\increment}
   },next state=line]{%
   \pgfmathparse{varyinglw(100*(\x/\pgfdecoratedpathlength))}
   \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgfmathresult pt}%
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\steplength}{1.4*\increment}
   \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\steplength pt}{0pt}}%
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{100*(\x/\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}
   \pgfsetstrokecolor{\endcolor!\y!\startcolor}%
   \pgfusepath{stroke}%
 }
 \state{final}{%
   \pgfsetlinewidth{\pgflinewidth}%
   \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
   \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{100*(\x/\pgfdecoratedpathlength)}
   \color{\endcolor!\y!\startcolor}%
   \pgfusepath{stroke}% 
 }
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={-70}{15}]
 \begin{scope}[perspective={p = {(20,0,0)}, q = {(0,20,0)}},switch on perspective]
  \path let \p1=($(0,2,0)-(0,0,0)$),\p2=($(20,2,0)-(20,0,0)$),
     \n1={atan2(\y1,\x1)/2+atan2(\y2,\x2)/2} in
   [left color=black,right color=gray!80!black,shading angle=\n1]
    (0,-3,0) -- (0,3,0) -- (20,3,0) -- (20,-3,0) -- cycle;
  \begin{scope}
   \clip (1,-3,0) -- (1,3,0) -- (20,3,0) -- (20,-3,0) -- cycle;
   \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,1.2,-1.2,-2}
   {\draw[decorate,decoration={width and color change}] let 
    \p1=($(10,\X+0.5,0)-(10,\X-0.5,0)$),\p2=($(1,\X+0.5,0)-(1,\X-0.5,0)$),
    \n1={sqrt(\x1*\x1+\y1*\y1)},\n2={sqrt(\x2*\x2+\y2*\y2)} in
    [declare function={varyinglw(\x)=0.1*\n1+0.1*(\n2-\n1)*\x/100;},
    /pgf/decoration/start color=gray!70!black,/pgf/decoration/end color=gray]
   (20,\X,0) -- (1,\X,0) coordinate (aux\Y);}
  \end{scope}   
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0]
  \fill[rotate=-15] foreach \X in {1,...,4} {(aux\X) circle[x radius=5pt,y radius=1pt]};
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Probably one can find parameter regions in which the curved paths work, too, but it might be a better investment of time to try to teach these decorations `fpu`.

Comment: It is a great answer!! Thanks a lot for investing so much time in it!!! I seriously need this answer as well but my given screenshot was just an imitation to be done from the code I provided. If my code is run, it gives a cylinder but can that cylinder be made sinusoidal was actually my question. I badly present it, however, this was actually my second part. Many thanks again!

Comment: I am sorry to wake you up again for this. But this beautiful answer is helping me a lot. However, I was unable to remove the angle the picture has with vertical axis. To be more precise, the cylindrical pipes are at some angle with the vertical axis, is there a way to remove this angle make them completely vertical (or straight)? Many thanks :)

Comment: @Shamina Straight with a perspective view or just straight (from the top of the screen to the bottom)?

Comment: Without perspective would do thee job.  Exactly from the top of the screen to the bottom!

Comment: @Shamina In the second code replace `\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={-70}{15}]
 \begin{scope}[perspective={p = {(20,0,0)}, q = {(0,20,0)}},switch on perspective]` by `\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{scope}[rotate=90]`, and remove `\fill[rotate=-15] foreach \X in {1,...,4} {(aux\X) circle[x radius=5pt,y radius=1pt]};`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Possibly last trouble, if I need the perspective on top of this?

Comment: @Shamina I think these statements are somewhat contradicting. You can use `\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90,3d view={0}{90}]
 \begin{scope}[switch on perspective]` and also remove the circles in the end. Now you can add some values of `perspective={p = {(20,0,0)}, q = {(0,20,0)}}` where you have to play with the entries of `p` and `q` until you are happy and get the perspective you want.

Comment: That solves my problem, many thanks to you. I guess the cylidrical pipes can still be made more darker? I mean more contrasting from the background color

Comment: @Shamina The colors are all stored in `/pgf/decoration/start color=gray!70!black,/pgf/decoration/end color=gray`, you can choose whatever color you like.